# How to execute a string fetched from a YAML file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have the following setup in my RailsApplication:

```
class MyClass 
  def self.perform_action! specific_name
     init = YAML.load_file('path/to/file.yml')[specific_name]
     input = init[:option1]
```

Here is the YAML file that gets loaded:

```
:MyName:
  :option1: 'Data::Executables::SpecificFunction.new.run!'
  :option2: 'Data::Executables::SpecificFunction.new.new_method'
```

Now, when I call MyClass.perform_action!(:MyName) it sure enough gets the value of `:option1` and sets it equal to `input`. What I need though is for that line to be executed; having it as a string is of no use.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute code in a string, you can use `eval`:

```
class MyClass 
  def self.perform_action! specific_name
     init = YAML.load_file('path/to/file.yml')[specific_name]
     input = init[:option1]
     result = eval(input)
```

I would only recommend this if you totally trust the YAML file, otherwise outsiders could have full access to your system, as `eval` runs any code passed to it, malicious or not.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am the only one having access to the YAML file, so I guess it's ok to do it like that. What would be an alternative solution?

Comment: I don't think there's an alternative in this case, but if you're the only one with access to the YAML file then it is relatively safe. Just be aware to never use `eval` with user-submitted code that you do not completely trust.

Answer (score 1):

for more security, you can store in yaml file method's names only

```
:MyName:
  :option1: 'new.run!'
  :option2: 'new.new_method'
```

and use method send

```
class MyClass 
  def self.perform_action! specific_name
    init = YAML.load_file('path/to/file.yml')[specific_name]
    chain = init[:option1].split('.')
    allowable_methods = Data::Executables::SpecificFunction
    result = chain.reduce(allowable_methods){|target, method| target.send method}
```